# How to run a JavaScript file for a specific country?

Tags: javascript

for example:

I have a code.js file and I want this file to run when I visit a specific country.

For example, if they came to my site from Canada, that file will be executed

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 3):

On server-side, you could just check the IP with something like https://ip-api.com/, get the geolocation back and deliver the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your file to be run must contain a function, which you can execute as shown below.

```
function geoFindMe() {
  if (!navigator.geolocation){
   console.log("Geolocation is not supported by your browser");
    return;
  }
  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    
    useMyCodeInAnotherFile();


     // Reverse geo coding goes here
  }
  function error() {
    console.log("Unable to retrieve your location");
  }
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

Now to get the country the user lives in, you can use [Google's reverse geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding). Keep in mind that you will need an API key and a google account